# How to change jax-ws to jax-rs without client sens of changes

Tags: java, web-services, jax-rs, jax-ws, spring-resttemplate

There is an application that was configured and has developed by JAX-WS; the piece of code like this:

```
@WebService(targetNamespace = "http://webservice.bulk.test.net/", serviceName = "BulkService")
@BindingType(value = SOAPBinding.SOAP12HTTP_BINDING)
@XmlSeeAlso({
        ObjectFactory.class
})
public class Bulk {

    @WebMethod
    @RequestWrapper(localName = "getProvinces", targetNamespace = "http://webservice.bulk.test.net/", className = "test.GetProvinces")
    @ResponseWrapper(localName = "getProvincesResponse", targetNamespace = "http://webservice.bulk.test.net/", className = "test.GetProvincesResponse")
    @Action(input = "http://webservice.bulk.test.net/Bulk/getProvincesRequest", output = "http://webservice.bulk.test.net/Bulk/getProvincesResponse")
    public void getProvinces(
            @WebParam(name = "username", targetNamespace = "") @XmlElement(nillable = false, required = true)
                    String username,
            @WebParam(name = "password", targetNamespace = "") @XmlElement(nillable = false, required = true)
                    String password,
...) {
}
```

According to this webservice, so many clients(jax-ws clients) are using.

I want to change the jax-ws to jax-rs without changing the client, another hand, the clients have no sens about the changes and do api-call as before.

Is it possible?

Comment: The short answer is that it is not possible.   (If I understand what you are asking correctly ...)

Comment: when the api endpoint does not change, why it is not possible?

Comment: Because the API >>will<< be different if you change from JAX-WS to JAX-RS.  The format of the messages and replies will be different, as will the URLs.  (Like I said ... this assumes I understand what you have said you intend to do correctly.)

Comment: So how I solve the technical debt? because the jax-rs is faster than jax-ws

Comment: You change the clients as well.

Comment: I am not able because of so many clients

Comment: Then you can't get rid of the technical debt.   Anyway, having lots of clients doesn't mean it is impossible to change an API.  Folks like Google do it all the time!   They say to all of their clients: *"On date X we will be turning off APV v1.  You need to have migrated to v2 by then ... or else you will lose access to the service."*

Comment: @StephenC I solved the problem according to answer of this question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this problem by separating soap layer from the application because of some reasons, first, used `Jax-rs and Jax-ws` endpoints simultaneously and secondly, is technical debt; due to separating soap from application, it is able to migrate to `JDK-11` without any problems and thirdly, according to separating Soap from application, it is independent from JAX-WS clients except changing JAX-WS endpoints.

Comment: That is essentially what my last comment said.  Your "v1" endpoint is jax-ws, and your "v2" endpoint is jax-rs.   (And of course you >STILL< need to replace the old clients in order to remove the technical debt ... of supporting a redundant endpoint.)

Comment: Yes of course but redundant api is not my concern. by separating, all technical debt such as jdk migration and others are solved.

Comment: Shrug ... semantics.  Technical debt it technical debt, whether or not you acknowledge it.  By saying you have removed "all technical debt" you are basically kidding yourself.  And you are potentially misleading other readers of your answer.

Comment: No, I mean except soap, the first I resolve others and the next I am going to resolve jax-ws porblem.